# cooldown format discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I didn't where to ask so I will ask here. (Sorry if this os a duplicated question or anything).

I have a command that I want to use every 2 hours, which I have done, but the cooldown error is my issue. I want to format it like: 1 hour, 30 mins. I have tried this but it does the hours in minutes and minutes in seconds.

```
@command.error
async def command_error(self, ctx, error):
 if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
 
        cd = round(error.retry_after)
        hours = str(cd // 3600)
        minutes = str(cd % 60)
        await ctx.send(f'You can use this command again in {hours} hour(s), {minutes} minute(s)')
```

I also tried this but it would display like 1.0 hours, 30.0 mins:

```
@command.error #thats the name of my command
    async def command_error(self, ctx, error):
     if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
 
        m, s = divmod(error.retry_after, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        d, h = divmod(h, 60)
        await ctx.send(f'You can use this command again in {h} hour(s), {m} minute(s)')
```

Anyone know a fix or something? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the time you can use something like this:

```py
    def better_time(self, cd:int):
        time = f"{cd}s"
        if cd > 60:
            minutes = cd - (cd % 60)
            seconds = cd - minutes
            minutes = int(minutes/ 60)
            time = f"{minutes}min {seconds}s"
            if minutes > 60:
                hoursglad = minutes -(minutes % 60)
                hours = int(hoursglad/ 60)
                minutes = minutes - (hours*60)
                time = f"{hours}h {minutes}min {seconds}s"
        return time
```

And to implement it into your code and send the remaining time you can just pass the following:

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    cd = round(error.retry_after)
    if cd == 0:
        cd = 1
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author.mention } - Cooldown, try again in** `{self.better_time(cd)}`**.**", delete_after=3)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but it still displays in seconds for some reason.

Comment: Even with my function built in correctly? Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Does it depend on the format? If so, how did you format it?

Comment: Coding is always format sensitive. Have a look at my new edit.

Comment: I input the code and it always tells me my await is outside async function if I try it..

Comment: Then put it inside the `async` function. You at least have to try things yourself as the error is self-explanatory.

Comment: I will try, thanks! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: So, when I did the code the way you said in your answer. It says that `cd` is undefined...

Comment: Do you know what I can do?

Comment: In which lien? It is pretty hard to follow your comments...

Comment: Right, I have my command first. Then i have the covert timer thing. Then i have my error handling..

Comment: Converter first, command second and error handling third.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. There is no mistake with the code and it works perfectly fine for me, can't help further if I do not get to see the code, sorry. Try sites where you can past your code and share the link.

Comment: Edited my post, have a look.

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH!

Comment: If it helped you do not forget to accept the answer. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Hi @Dominik, I know it's been nearly a year or so since I made this post (I don't know if you can contact users on stackoverflow) but I did want to ask, that code you gave me works great! But I want to it to display days as well, do you know how to do it? I have tried to do it but couldn't get it to work, here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819725/cooldown-format-in-days-discord-py) I asked if anyone knew. Thanks.