# Cooldown format in days discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently making a command which has a cooldown of 5 days, and I'm currently using this code for the cooldown.

```
def better_time(self, cd:int):
        time = f"{cd}s"
        if cd > 60:
            minutes = cd - (cd % 60)
            seconds = cd - minutes
            minutes = int(minutes/ 60)
            time = f"{minutes} minutes {seconds} seconds"
            if minutes > 60:
                hoursglad = minutes -(minutes % 60)
                hours = int(hoursglad/ 60)
                minutes = minutes - (hours*60)
                time = f"{hours} hours {minutes} minutes {seconds} seconds"
        return time
```

How would I do days? I have tried the following (it has confused me):

````
def better_time(self, cd:int):
        time = f"{cd} seconds"
        if cd > 60:
            minutes = cd - (cd % 60)
            seconds = cd - minutes
            minutes = int(minutes/ 60)
            time = f"{minutes} minutes {seconds} second(s)"
            if minutes > 60:
                hoursglad = minutes -(minutes % 60)
                hours = int(hoursglad/ 60)
                minutes = minutes - (hours*60)
                time = f"{hours} hours {minutes} minute(s) {seconds} second(s)"
                if hours > 86400:
                    daysglad = minutes -(hours % 60)
                    days = int(daysglad/ 60)
                    minutes = minutes - (days*60)
                    time = f"{days} days {minutes} minute(s) {seconds} second(s)"
                    return time
    ```

Yes, I know it's wrong, it has confused me.
````

Comment: why don't you use datetime?

Comment: as for me you should start at days, later hours, later minutes and seconds. - `days = cd // 86400` and `rest = cd % 86400` and later `hours = rest // (60*60)` and `rest = rest  % (60*60)` and later `minutes = rest // 60` and `seconds = rest % 60`

Answer (score 0):

You should starts at days, later hours, later minutes and seconds

```
cd = 500_000

days = cd // 86400    # 24*60*60 seconds
rest = cd  % 86400

hours = rest // 3600  #    60*60 seconds
rest  = rest  % 3600

minutes = rest // 60  #       60 seconds
seconds = rest  % 60

print(f"{cd} seconds = {days} day(s) {hours} hour(s) {minutes} minute(s) {seconds} second(s)")
```

Result:

```
500000 seconds = 5 day(s) 18 hour(s) 53 minute(s) 20 seconds(s)
```

And if you want to display shorter version when there is no days/hours/minutes/seconds then you could use `if/else` after caculating all values

```
result = [f"{cd} seconds ="]

if days:
    result.append(f"{days} day(s)")

if hours:
    result.append(f"{hours} hour(s)")
    
if minutes:
    result.append(f"{minutes} minute(s)")

if seconds:
    result.append(f"{seconds} seconds(s)")
    
print(" ".join(result))
```